# How to spawn new processes for new instances of the same shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script, ksh

I'm trying to lock a file using the command lock. Its syntax is

```
./lock </path/to/file/name>
```

I need to lock a bunch of files in a given directory and in order to achieve this I'm using two scripts:

1. `parent.sh`
2. `child.sh`

`parent.sh` will call a `child.sh` process for every file. So, if I need to lock 9 files I will have `parent.sh` spawn 9 `child.sh` but unfortunately this isn't happening.

```
[root@localhost /]# cat parent.sh
#!/bin/ksh
for f in /vol4/commit/file[1-9]
do
 sh /child.sh & $f
done

[root@localhost /]# cat child.sh
#!/bin/ksh
./lock $1
```

When I run `sh parent.sh`, I got the following error

```
[root@localhost /]# sh parent.sh
parent.sh: line 4: /vol4/commit/file1: Permission denied
parent.sh: line 4: /vol4/commit/file2: Permission denied
parent.sh: line 4: /vol4/commit/file3: Permission denied
parent.sh: line 4: /vol4/commit/file4: Permission denied
parent.sh: line 4: /vol4/commit/file5: Permission denied
parent.sh: line 4: /vol4/commit/file6: Permission denied
parent.sh: line 4: /vol4/commit/file7: Permission denied
parent.sh: line 4: /vol4/commit/file8: Permission denied
parent.sh: line 4: /vol4/commit/file9: Permission denied
```

Since I'm running as root, I didn't expect any permissions issue here but that's what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Line 4 of `parent.sh`, you wrote `sh /child.sh & $f`. The ampersand must be put at the end of the command like that: `sh /child.sh $f &`.

In your case, you are trying to run `sh /child.sh` in background, and then you are executing `$f` in foreground, which will lead to a permission denied as I can assume that your files `/vol4/commit/file[1-9]` are not executable.

Also, you might want to note that if your file is in read only, you might not be able to edit it or acquire write lock, even for root.